# How can I get several similar tags data with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: html-agility-pack, data-extraction

Before explaining, I am using VB.net and HtmlAgilityPack.

I have the below html, all three sections have the same format. I am using htmlagilitypack to extract the data from the Title and Date. My code extracts the title correctly but the date is only extracted from the first instance and repeated 3 times:

HtmlAgilityPack code:

```
For Each h4 As HtmlNode In docnews.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h4[(@class='title')]")
    Dim date1 As HtmlNode = docnews.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[starts-with(@class, 'date ')]")
    Dim newsdate As String = date1.InnerText
    MessageBox.Show(h4.InnerText)
    MessageBox.Show(newsdate)
Next
```

I thought being in each h4, I get its associated date accordingly...

HTML code:

```
<div  class="article-header" style="" data-itemid="920729" data-source="ABC" data-preview="Text 1">
<h4 class="title"><a href="URL" class="title" title="Text 1">Text for Mr. A</a></h4>
    <div class="byline">
        <span class="date timestamp"><span  title="29 November 2013">29-11-2013</span></span>
        <span class="source" title="AGE">18</span>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">Text 1 Preview</div>
</div>

<div  class="article-header" style="" data-itemid="920720" data-source="ABC" data-preview="Text 2">
<h4 class="title"><a href="URL" class="title" title="Text 2">Text for Mr. B</a></h4>
    <div class="byline">
        <span class="date timestamp"><span  title="27 November 2013">27-11-2013</span></span>
        <span class="source" title="AGE">25</span>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">Text 2 Preview</div>
</div>

<div  class="article-header" style="" data-itemid="920719" data-source="ABC" data-pre+view="Text 3">
<h4 class="title"><a href="URL" class="title" title="Text 3">Text for Mr. C</a></h4>
    <div class="byline">
        <span class="date timestamp"><span  title="22 October 2013">22-10-2013</span></span>
        <span class="source" title="AGE">20</span>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">Text 3 Preview</div>
</div>
```

Final Output should be:

> Text for Mr. A
>
> 29-11-2013
>
> Text for Mr. B
>
> 27-11-2013
>
> Text for Mr. C
>
> 22-10-2013

What I am getting with my code:

> Text for Mr. A
>
> 29-11-2013
>
> Text for Mr. B
>
> 29-11-2013
>
> Text for Mr. C
>
> 29-11-2013

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor your second XPath to look 'below' the `h4`:

```
Dim date1 As HtmlNode = h4.Parent.SelectSingleNode(".//span[starts-with(@class, 'date ')]")
                        ^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^
```

The `.//` tells Xpath to look under the node the Xpath is executed on. Thus by calling `SelectSingleNode` on the `h4.Parent` you get the date below the parent `div` tag of the `h4`.

Comment: I tried the code and it generated 'System.NullReferenceException' error but when i removed the .// and replaced it with //, it worked the same way as it was working before.. same date to all three instances... thanks you for your prompt reply !

Comment: `//` will search from the root node. It must start with `.//`

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing, i guess i know where my error is, the h4 tag closes before the date... Will work on it now. Thanks again !